# Chrome Extension with lasting data (data storage)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I´currently trying to get my first chrome extension running. It is a very simple application to learn some Javascript and manage some data. I already managed to get my simple extension running but the problem is if I close the extension or click somewhere else on the page the data in the extension is lost. So I guess the extension restarts every time you click on the icon.
  But I want the data to stay in my extension even if I switch to another page or close the `HTML`-window of the extension.

**How can I manage that the data will be stored during the runtime of my extension ?**

Here is the code of my application. At this point the button just adds 5 to the `stake` element to see if he value will be stored or not.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Betting Extension",
  "description": "This extension will analyze your account history",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
   "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

---

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Tipico Analyzer</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    </head>

    <body style="width: 100px">
        <p>stake: <span id="stake">0</span>€</p>
        <p>profit: <span id="profit">0</span> €</p>
        <p>winning: <span id="winning">0</span> €</p>
        <button id="addPage">Add page</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('addPage');
    checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

        d = document;
        var stake = parseFloat(d.getElementById('stake').innerHTML);


        document.getElementById('stake').innerHTML = stake + 5;

    }, false);


}, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to store the data during the runtime of your extension.

1. Set a variable in [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages): by setting `"persistent": true` in `manifest.json`, the background page will be running through the runtime of your extension.
2. Use [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage): you can use this api to store, retrieve and track changes to the data. Data in `chrome.storage` is available even after restarts, but it will be lost if your extension is uninstalled.

   ```
   chrome.storage.local.get([key], function (result) {
    var value = result[key];
   });
   chrome.storage.local.set({key: val});
   ```
3. Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

   ```
   var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
   localStorage.setItem(key, value);
   ```

Comment: Of note: the pattern of assigning a `value` inside the `get()` is dangerous -  it can [lead to errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) if the fact that `chrome.storage` is asynchronous is not communicated.